# Reuse already open Excel Worksheet from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am importing data from Outlook. The code for opening Excel opens an instance where personal.xlsb is not loaded, and will open multiple instances of Excel. If I run it twice it will open two instances but will overwrite the data in the first instance, leaving the second instance with a blank workbook. If Excel is closed and Outlook is not, then the code is run it will give an error since it won't put the data into the new "second" instance, even though only one instance is running.

```
Sub Extract()
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set mynamespace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("mapi")

    Dim ThermoMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set ThermoMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

    Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application")
    xlobj.Visible = True
    xlobj.Workbooks.Add
    'Set Headings

    Dim msgText, delimtedMessage, Delim1 As String
    delimtedMessage = ThermoMail.Body

    'Remove everything before "Lead Source:" and after "ELMS"
    TrimmedArray = Split(delimtedMessage, "Source:")
    delimtedMessage = TrimmedArray(1)
    TrimmedArray = Split(delimtedMessage, "ELMS")
    delimtedMessage = TrimmedArray(0)

    'Split the array at each return
    messageArray = Split(delimtedMessage, vbCrLf)
    'this next line gives the error if excel is closed and the macro is rerun.
    Range("A1:A" & UBound(messageArray) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(messageArray)
    Call splitAtColons

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are creating a new instance of Excel with this line:

```
 Set xlobj = CreateObject("excel.application")
```

Excel is different than some (most) Office Applications, because it can run multiple instances (PowerPoint, Outlook, Word cannot do this...)

So what you want to do is first check if there is an open instance of Excel, and use that. Only create a new instance if there is no instance already open.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlObj = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If xlObj Is Nothing Then Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```